# Ruby mixin best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to Ruby\Rails, shame on me :(

I'm developing an engine for personal use (simple admin panel). What I want, is to be able to config my main app's models, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Entropy::Configurable

  entropy_config do
    form_caption 'Editing user'
  end
end
```

And then in engine's templates do this:

```
<h1><%= @object.entropy_config :form_caption %></h1>
```

Engine's module:

```
module Entropy
  module Configurable

    def self.included(base)
      ## to call entropy_config in model class
      base.send :extend, ClassMethods
    end

    def entropy_config(arg)
      ## ... I'm missing this part
    end

    module ClassMethods

      @@config = { ... }

      def entropy_config (&block)
        class_eval &block
      end

      def form_caption(arg)
        // skipping class identification
        @@config[:user][:form_caption] = arg
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that I can not get access to @@config from Configurable module, actually when I call entropy_config on @object. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean have no access, the variable doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you've doing it wrong. Rails is on of the frameworks that pushed a lot on the MVC architecture. Having your model know about form captions is wrong. For that I would use the rails i18n gem. For the sake of the argument here's some untested code that will probably answer your question:

```
module Entropy
  module Configurable

    def self.included(base)
      ## to call entropy_config in model class
      base.send :extend, ClassMethods
    end

    def entropy_config(key)
      self.class.config[:user][key]
    end

    module ClassMethods

      cattr_accessor :config

      def entropy_config (&block)
        self.config ||= {}
        class_eval &block
      end

      def form_caption(arg)
        // skipping class identification
        self.config[:user][:form_caption] = arg
      end
    end
  end
end
```

see http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor for more info

Comment: Thank you! The deal is not only about titles, but more about admin config, form fields set for example, or fields in list

Comment: Still I believe the model is not a suitable place for it. If you don't want to define the fields in the views you should create some separate objects for that. See how activeadmin works https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin

Comment: btw ... as a rails tip: whenever you need some component search rubygems.org (or ruby-toolbox.com) for it as it's a good chance that somebody already developed that component :)